# HTTP Errors with AWS ALB

Tags: python, java, amazon-web-services, http, aws-application-load-balancer

I am having basic HTTP related issues when sending a python post request to my AWS ALB which routes traffic to a Java WebSocket.
In terms of my client I am trying to send an HTTP post by sending the following python string to my ALB:

```
headers = """\
    POST / HTTP/1.1\r
    Content-Type: {content_type}\r
    Content-Length: {content_length}\r
    Host: {host}\r
    Connection: close\r
    \r\n"""

    post_dict = {"totalPartitionCount": 3}
    body = bytes(json.dumps(post_dict),encoding="utf-8")
    header_bytes = headers.format(
        content_type="text/plain",
        content_length=len(body),
        host=str(albAddr) + ":" + str(8080)
    ).encode('utf-8')

    payload = header_bytes + body

    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect((albAddr, 8080))

    s.sendall(payload)
   ...
```

But in running this I am returned a 400 Bad format Error.
Similarly, my health checks to my AWS ALB are failing from the java server when sending an http response:

```
        ServerSocket s = new ServerSocket(8081);
        while(true) {
            Socket sock = s.accept();
            System.out.println("Sending Status OK...");
            String httpResponse = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n";


            byte[] out = httpResponse.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

            try {
                sock.getOutputStream().write(out);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Error in Writing Health Check Response");
            }
            System.out.println("OK status sent.");
            sock.close();

        }
```

[image: AWS Health Check settings]

Am I making simple mistakes regarding HTTP? I have looked at multiple different sources on how http requests are being formatted in python and java and have tried to use those but haven't found any luck. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What is the ALB health check status to your java application? (to / 8081)

Is the target group in `InService` status? There are some [reasons](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-troubleshooting.html#target-not-inservice) the it's not `Inservice`

a bit confused - are your ALB listening to tcp/8080 and the health check is on tcp/8081?

The [400 error](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-troubleshooting.html#http-400-issues) looks like that is related to the backend code. not the health check.

What if you send the request to the backend without the ALB? Coudl you get a valid response from your python code?

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. Yes the 400 error code is related to me not sending the right http format, I just can’t figure out how to make the right format in python or java(I don’t know what I’m missing). The health check is happening on port 8081, so alb should be pinging the container on that port and I would have to respond(right now it returns internal error I think because my response string is not right). Everything works fine without ALB with using sockets so im pretty sure I’m not making http strings correctly. As a side note curl works with the alb.